# Setting state array in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, local-storage

I have been trying to push an object into a state array and then into local storage so it can remain visible even after refreshing, everything works fine except final push doesent happen. In order for an object to stay saved in local i have to add it and one after it, and the one after dont get saved. Any help is much appreciated

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([{ name: "", thumbnail: { path: "" } }]);
  const [team, setTeam] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("team")));
  console.log(team);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?apikey="
    )
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data.data.results));
  }, []);

  const addToTeam = (hero) => {
    !team ? setTeam([hero]) : setTeam([...team, hero]);
    localStorage.setItem("team", JSON.stringify(team));
  };
```

Comment: what doesnt work exactly? the localStorage or the setTeam?

Comment: they both work, except in order for first added object to be visible after refresh i need to add one after it, only then it stays in local storage. Its allways one step behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React state updates are not synchronous.
So when you run this code:

```
  const addToTeam = (hero) => {
    !team ? setTeam([hero]) : setTeam([...team, hero]);
    localStorage.setItem("team", JSON.stringify(team));
  };
```

you could be setting previous value of `team` instead of the value you just set.

To fix the problem you can make a side effect that runs when the `team` state changes and update localStorage from it.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("team", JSON.stringify(team));
}, [team]);
```

Comment: Thank you good sir, today you taught me something. It works now :D

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer